# GWR package use for cross validation

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement a GWR model for my data on PM2.5 data with 163 observations. I'm using the GWmodel package.

Here is what I did :

```
PM25dist <- PM25
coordinates(PM25dist) <- c('Longitude','Latitude')
dm.calib <- gw.dist(dp.locat = coordinates(PM25dist))
PM25dist <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = PM25dist, data = as.data.frame(PM25dist))
bw_cv[["gaussian"]][["CV"]] <- bw.gwr(as.formula(models[[1]]),
                                        data = PM25dist, 
                                        approach = "CV", 
                                        kernel = "gaussian", 
                                        adaptive = TRUE) 
  mod_gwr <- gwr.basic(formula = as.formula(models[[1]]),  
                       data = PM25dist, 
                       kernel = "gaussian", 
                       adaptive = TRUE, 
                       bw= as.numeric(bw_cv$gaussian$CV), 
                       cv=TRUE)
```

this is my model but then I'm trying to implement a cross_validation :

```
X <- PM25[,c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5")]
X <- cbind(FirstColumn = rep(1, nrow(X)), X)
coord <- as.matrix(PM25[, c('Longitude', 'Latitude')])
coord[, 'Longitude'] <- as.numeric(coord[, 'Longitude'])
coord[, 'Latitude'] <- as.numeric(coord[, 'Latitude'])

DM<-gw.dist(dp.locat=coordinates(coord))
gwr.cv.contrib(as.numeric(bw_cv$gaussian$CV), X, y_PM25, 
       kernel="Gaussian",
       dp.locat = coord,
       adaptive=TRUE,
       dMat = DM) # ??
```

My problem is that I don't know what to put in dMat. The documentation indicates that : "a pre-specified distance matrix, it can be calculated by the function gw.dist" but it's not clear how to use this function.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Does the `gwr.cv.contrib()` function work? It looks like it should because you have supplied it with a distance matrix?

Comment: No it doesn't work. I get the message error : "Error in gw_weight_vec(vdist, bw, kernel, adaptive) : 
  Expecting a single value: [extent=0]."

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of your code?